# LoadPackage call failed error msg when trying to create an Azure Project in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

When attempting to create an Azure project in Visual Studio 2010 I get a dialog box with an error msg stating "LoadPackage call failed".

The Visual Studio ActivityLog shows the following errors:

> 466 ERROR CreateInstance failed for package
>   [Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.CloudService,
>   Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]
>   {CCE67B96-C6C0-4765-93CB-995CF3BF913C} 80070002 VisualStudio
>   2012/05/12 18:14:17.357
>
> 467 ERROR End package load [Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectPackage,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CloudService, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]
>   {CCE67B96-C6C0-4765-93CB-995CF3BF913C} 80004005 - E_FAIL VisualStudio
>   2012/05/12 18:14:17.359
>
> 468 Warning Package failed to load; error message suppressed by skip
>   flag {CCE67B96-C6C0-4765-93CB-995CF3BF913C}  VisualStudio 2012/05/12
>   18:14:17.360  469  Entering function
>   CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage
>   {CCE67B96-C6C0-4765-93CB-995CF3BF913C}  VisualStudio 2012/05/12
>   18:14:17.399
>
> 470  Begin package load [Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectPackage,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CloudService, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]
>   {CCE67B96-C6C0-4765-93CB-995CF3BF913C}  VisualStudio 2012/05/12
>   18:14:17.402
>
> 471 ERROR CreateInstance failed for package
>   [Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.CloudService,
>   Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]
>   {CCE67B96-C6C0-4765-93CB-995CF3BF913C} 80070002 VisualStudio
>   2012/05/12 18:14:17.403
>
> 472 ERROR End package load [Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectPackage,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.CloudService, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a]
>   {CCE67B96-C6C0-4765-93CB-995CF3BF913C} 80004005 - E_FAIL VisualStudio
>   2012/05/12 18:14:17.404
>
> 473 Warning Package failed to load; error message suppressed by skip
>   flag {CCE67B96-C6C0-4765-93CB-995CF3BF913C}  VisualStudio 2012/05/12
>   18:14:17.406

When trying to load any azure projects another dialog box appears:

> 'HelloWorld.ccproj' cannot be opened because its project types (.ccproj) is not supported by this version of the application.

Similar errors appear in the ActivityLog in this instance as well, referencing the same CctProjectPackage assemblies.

---

Thus far I've tried installing, removing and reinstalling the latest versions of

- Windows Azure SDK
- VSCloudService.exe
- Windows Azure Tools
- Windows Azure Libs for .NET

I've tried using the web platform installer to install the necessary tools.  I've even gone so far as to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 SP1 as well as remove and reinstall Visual Studio.

None of this has resolved the issue.   I've tried searching for explanations on why the Microsoft.Cct.CctProjectPackage or Microsoft.VisualStudio.CloudService assemblies don't seem to load via Google and the only suggestion seems to be to reinstall the tools, which didn't work.  I've even gone so far as to try searching on Bing.

I'm out of ideas and would appreciate insights from anyone else who may have experienced similar problems or could recommend other things to try.

Comment: _I've even gone so far as to try searching on Bing._  You poor thing ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Microsoft support the issue has been resolved.  It turns out that Azure Tools 1.3 hadn't been properly uninstalled which meant Visual Studio was looking for files from it when trying to load Azure projects, regardless of newer versions having been installed.

The solution was to reinstall Azure Tools 1.3 and then uninstall it again.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to know what OS you are using. If you’re using an OS version between Windows Vista and Windows Server 2008 R2, the installation process would be straightforward. Please make sure you have the latest OS service pack and Visual Studio service pack. If you’re using an earlier version of OS, such as Windows XP, it cannot not be installed Windows Azure SDK. Please also check if a third party plug-in for Visual Studio may cause issues. If you’re using Windows 8, it cannot use the all in one package. Please install each component separately. it also need to enable several Windows components. I would like to suggest you to check http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/other-resources/windows-azure-on-windows-8/ for more information.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm running Windows 7 and disabling any extensions has no effect (I only have 2 and they're minor) and as previously suggested, I tried installing both through the web platform installer as well as manually.  Neither resolved the issue

Comment: I do not know how this can happen. Please try to contact our customer support on https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?gprid=14928&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn. Maybe they will be able to help. If not, you may need to find another machine, or reinstall OS to see whether it works.

Comment: Thanks Ming, Microsoft support was able to identify the issue and help me resolve it.